Py_INCREF in Cython accepts Python object but not pointer
I have a small implementation of a linked list in Cython, and I wish to add a value to the list.
For some reason, when I try to Py_INCREF (to make sure I keep a strong reference in each node), Cython does not accept a pointer to the Python object, but only the object itself:
ctypedef struct Node:
    PyObject* group
    PyObject* value  # (group, value)
    Node* next

cdef bint _put(object group, object value) except 1:
    cdef:
        Node* node = <Node*>PyMem_Malloc(sizeof(Node))
        PyObject* _group = <PyObject*> group
        PyObject* _value = <PyObject*> value
    
    if not node:
        raise MemoryError("Failed to allocate memory for new node")

    node.group = _group
    Py_INCREF(node.group)  # Cannot convert 'PyObject *' to Python object
    Py_INCREF(_group)  # Cannot convert 'PyObject *' to Python object
    Py_INCREF(<PyObject*> group)  # Cannot convert 'PyObject *' to Python object
    Py_INCREF(group)  # Works

Supposedly, Py_INCREF is meant to work with PyObject*.
Both looking up around the web and chatgpt directly suggested that:

Py_INCREF in Cython works with a PyObject*, which is a pointer to
a Python object, not a Python-level object. Therefore, you should pass
a PyObject* (a pointer) to Py_INCREF.

The code seems so simple, I'm unsure why it doesn't work.

Presumably you've cimported it from cpython.ref?
That's largely just because of how it's defined:
    void Py_INCREF(object o)

The convention that Cython generally uses is:

object if it cannot be NULL
PyObject* if it can be NULL.

Since INCREF doesn't accept NULL arguments then it's object. XINCREF which does accept NULL arguments is PyObject*.
Even if you don't like that convention, it'd be very hard to change at this stage because there's a large amount of code that uses the current definition.

You've got two options:

Cast to object:
Py_INCREF(<object>node.group)


Write your own definition that fits how you want it (the C API definitions that Cython exposes don't do anything that you can't do yourself):
cdef extern from "Python.h":
   void Py_INCREF(PyObject* o)




I've been bashing my head at this for hours. Thank you very much.
If I understand correctly, casting to an object will require refcounting needlessly back and forth (i.e. Cython will INCREF upon conversion to object, INCREF again using the function and DECREF upon object teardown) so I think using the extern is the better version. Is there anywhere in the documentation that shows the convention or mentions any of it? I feel as if the documentation is a tad lacking

Casting to an object just to pass an argument should not change the reference count, so both options are basically equivalent (do inspect the generated code to double-check though). Assigning to an object variable (e.g. cdef object o = <object>something) will change the reference count being going through an object temp won't.

Not sure there's too much documentation for this unfortunately.
